# Versioning gems in Rails 4 that handle has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, versioning, paper-trail-gem

I am building a Rails 4 application that is heavily dependent on has_many associations at several levels.  I would love to use a gem like paper_trail to handle versioning, but it [does not handle](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#associations) has_many associations, [at least not yet](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/148).  However, [older gems](https://github.com/kkurach/has_versioning) seem to have supported this behavior in previous versions of Rails.  Is there an equivalent Rails 4 solution?

Answer (score 0):

It does now (in version 4.0.0), Limited support for versioning associations (has_one and has_many).

You need to have a separate table for handling associations, also transaction_id column added to the versions table.
However, there are still some caveats and limitations as they state in [here](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#associations).

Also look at:
https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400